Angular 18.1.0 mime.js:24 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
Al hacer ng serve de mi aplicacion, la pagina se muestra en blanco, al ir a la consola encuentro lo siguiente. Estoy empezando a aprender desarrollo web por lo que este tipo de errores se me hacen dificiles de entender:
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at Mime.define (mime.js:24:7)
    at node_modules/send/node_modules/mime/mime.js (mime.js:80:6)
    at __require2 (chunk-EIB7IA3J.js?v=6c094420:40:50)
    at node_modules/send/index.js (index.js:23:12)
    at __require2 (chunk-EIB7IA3J.js?v=6c094420:40:50)
    at node_modules/express/lib/utils.js (utils.js:19:12)
    at __require2 (chunk-EIB7IA3J.js?v=6c094420:40:50)
    at node_modules/express/lib/application.js (application.js:23:19)
    at __require2 (chunk-EIB7IA3J.js?v=6c094420:40:50)
    at node_modules/express/lib/express.js (express.js:17:13)

Las versiones instaladas son las siguientes:
Angular CLI: 18.1.0
Node: 20.11.1
Package Manager: npm 10.2.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 18.1.0
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server
... router, ssr

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1801.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular   18.1.0
@angular-devkit/core            18.1.0
@angular-devkit/schematics      18.1.0
@schematics/angular             18.1.0
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.5.3
zone.js                         0.14.7

edit 1: Una solucion que encontre es agregar lo siguiente en index.html:
<script>window.process = { env: { NODE_ENV: 'production' } };</script>

Pero lo unico que logre es que cambie el mensaje de error:
TypeError: util.inherits is not a function
    at node_modules/send/index.js (index.js:134:6)
    at __require2 (chunk-EIB7IA3J.js?v=6c094420:40:50)
    at node_modules/express/lib/utils.js (utils.js:19:12)
    at __require2 (chunk-EIB7IA3J.js?v=6c094420:40:50)
    at node_modules/express/lib/application.js (application.js:23:19)
    at __require2 (chunk-EIB7IA3J.js?v=6c094420:40:50)
    at node_modules/express/lib/express.js (express.js:17:13)
    at __require2 (chunk-EIB7IA3J.js?v=6c094420:40:50)
    at node_modules/express/index.js (index.js:11:18)
    at __require2 (chunk-EIB7IA3J.js?v=6c094420:40:50)


Te explicaré el contexto del error para que entiendas qué está sucediendo.
En el primero error que agregas, el stack trace nos indica que mime.js encontró una excepción al ejecutar la función Mime.define, sin embargo al final del stack trace nos muestra que el error en sí se originó en express.js.
El error que lees índica que la propiedad global process no está definida, la cual es una propiedad que la librería express está intentando acceder y process es una propiedad única de Nodejs.
Aunque Angular requiere Nodejs para desarrollar y construir aplicaciones, el contexto en el que la aplicación corre es en el navegador (cliente) y recordemos que Nodejs corre como servidor.
La solución que encontraste es algo se llama polyfill, lo cual es código que simula o agrega compatibilidad.
En este caso, la solución no es esa ya que el último error que agregas hace referencia a la librería express la cual falla al utilizar una función única de Nodejs (util.inherits).
Esto quiere decir que tu aplicación de navegador está utilizando una librería exclusiva para NodeJS la cual el navegador no puede hacer funcionar bien.
Recomiendo que ejecutes npm list express para saber qué librería está usando express como dependencia, cuando tengas el resultado considera remover la libreria de tu proyecto y buscar otra alternativa.

Al ejecutar npm list express obtengo lo siguiente:                                                      @angular-devkit/build-angular@18.1.0
-- webpack-dev-server@5.0.4     -- express@4.19.2                                                                                                              Eliminar esta libreria me interrumpiria el correcto funcionamiento de angular verdad?

Interrumpiría el desarrollo.
¿Hay alguna parte de tu código donde llames a express? Lo dudo pero entonces me suena a incompatibilidad de la librería mime.js

No, yo en ningún momento hago una llamada a express. Probé creando desde cero el proyecto pero esta vez al crearlo no use el -- standalone=false. Quizás se debe a que estaba acostumbrado a trabajar con versiones sin standalone y cometí algún error ahí. Gracias por la ayuda amigo. Sin el standalone mi proyecto funciona perfectamente
